# Built-In callable as a default argument for a Django Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a JSONField that I need to apply a default dictionary to. As per the documentation, I am avoiding passing the mutable dictionary to the default field. This is done by instead passing the copy method to the default argument like such:

```
default_dict = {'some_key': 'some value'}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.JSONField(default=default_dict.copy)
```

When applying makemigrations, this is failing because of the following condition in django.db.migrations.serializer.FunctionTypeSerializer:

```
if self.value.__module__ is None:
    raise ValueError("Cannot serialize function %r: No module" % self.value)
```

I can get around this by defining a callable that returns a copy, but I think this is adding unnecessary syntax and makes it harder to read:

```
class ADict(dict):
    def __call__(self):
        return self.copy()

default_dict = ADict({'some_key': 'some value'})

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.JSONField(default=default_dict)
```

Is there a way to pass a built-in objects method as the default value for a Django field?

Comment: You can't do this since it basically needs to be a *named* function, whereas `default_dict.copy` is an "anonymous" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this since it basically needs to be a *named* function, whereas `default_dict.copy` is an "anonymous" function.

You can however make a named function like:

```
default_dict = {'some_key': 'some value'}

def copy_default_dict():
    return default_dict.copy()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.JSONField(default=copy_default_dict)
```

or even simpler:

```
def copy_default_dict():
    return {'some_key': 'some value'}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.JSONField(default=copy_default_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, that's what I had thought. Is there a reason that this constraint exists? Looking "behind the curtain", I couldn't work out why this is not allowed. Removing the exception meant that it was trying to import None

Comment: @StuartBuckingham: it is not really a constraint. The problem is that it needs to appear in the migration files. With a named function, the migrations import the function. For a anonymous function it is from a Django point-of-view impossible to reconstruct the sequence of events to produce the object.

Comment: If it is a member method, like mydict.copy, could you not just import mydict by looking at the __self__ value of the anonymous function passed in and then getattr(mydict, func.__name__)?

Comment: @StuartBuckingham: the annonimity originates from the fact that you have an object. Note that Django simply receives the method itself, not the object. So you can see the `'copy'` method, but from what object? What if it was `{**foo, **bar}.copy` with `foo` and `bar` dictionaries, then the object is a "temporary" one.

Comment: True. Thank you for the detail.